# A question about adjoint representation of a compact and connected Lie group.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

I have already uploaded [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840008/a-question-while-pvoing-existence-bi-invariant-volume-element-on-a-compact-and-c?noredirect=1#comment7920919_3840008) before, but since it seems that the previous question is so verbose, I rewrite it. My question: Let $G$ be a compact and connected Lie group, and consider an adjoint representation of such Lie group, $Ad(g)$ whose matrix component is denoted by $(\alpha_{ij}(g))$. Then **why the determinant of adjoint representation matrix is only $+1$,i.e $det(Ad(g))=+1$.**

Comment: As Ted indicates in his comment, you want to show that the only connected compact subgroup of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ (under multiplication) is $\{1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a compact connected Lie group $G$ has a real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, and the adjoint action of G is naturally acting on $\mathfrak{g}$ by $Ad(g): \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$, $ X \mapsto gXg^{-1}$ for $g \in G, X \in \mathfrak{g}$.

Suppose we have a norm on $\mathfrak{g}$, for example, $\langle X,X \rangle = Tr(X  X)$ (trace form), then $\langle Ad(g)X, Ad(g)X \rangle = Tr(gXg^{-1} gXg^{-1}) = Tr(X  X) = \langle X,X \rangle$.

Since $\mathfrak{g}$ is real, this means $Ad(g)$ must be orthogonal transformation, so the determinant of $Ad(g)$ has to be $1$ or $-1$.